# Angular Validators.required is not going with ngIf hide/show

Tags: angular, typescript, validation

Angular 12, reactive form, when selecting **Yes** for `Adult`, user is required to enter an age, else no need.

HTML:

```
Are you adult?
<input type="radio" formControlName="Adult" value="1"/><label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" formControlName="Adult" value="0"/><label>No</label>

<div *ngIf="fg.controls['Adult'].value==1">
Enter your age: <input type="text" placeholder="18-120" formControlName="Age" size="5"/>
</div>
```

TS:

```
public fg: FormGroup;
this.fg = this.fb.group
(
  {
    Adult: ['', [Validators.required]],
    Age: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(18), Validators.max(120)]]
  }
)
```

Angular is not smart enough to ignore validation because of hide/show. Formgroup `fg.valid` is `false` when user selects **No**, even though `Age` is hidden. One way to handle this dynamic thing is to hardcode the logic with `addValidators([...]) / clearValidators() / setValidators([...])` then `updateValueAndValidity()`.
Is there a better way?

**Update**
What I want is Angular to skip below validation rule when user chooses **Yes** because `Age` is hidden.

```
Age: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(18), Validators.max(120)]]
```

To achieve that, I now have to

- attach a `(blur)=dynamicAge()` to `Adult` radio button
- inside `dynamicAge()` to check and set validation rule for `Age` like below.

TS

```
private dynamicAge()
{
  if (fg.controls['Adult'].value == 0) // not Adult
  {
    fg.controls['Age'].clearValidators(); // so fg.valid becomes true.
    fg.controls['Age'].updateValueAndValidity();
  }
}
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to `Adult` form control `valueChanges` then based on your condition you can enable or disable form.

When you disable form control angular will automatically exclude validation check

```
 get ageControl(){
   return this.fg.get('Age') as FormControl;
 }

 this.fg.get('Adult').valueChanges.subscribe(()=>{
      if(value ==1){
        this.ageControl.enable()
      }else{
        this.ageControl. disable();
     }
 });
```

Comment: OP - This will work but `[value]="1"` etc. is needed else it'll be a string

Answer (score 0):

I recently did something like this in my app:

```html
<kendo-maskedtextbox formControlName="webrelay_input_4_alarm_name"
    [disabled]="!ConfigForm.get('webrelay_input_4_alarm_used')?.value">
</kendo-maskedtextbox>
```

Your code:

```html
<form [formGroup]="fg" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(fg)">
    <div *ngIf="fg.get['Adult']?.value == 1">
        Enter your age:
        <input type="text" placeholder="18-120" formControlName="Age" size="5" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. May I ask where is the validation rule for `Age`?

Comment: @Jeb50 when a control no longer appears in the form (via `ngIf`), then the form does not consider it when validating

Comment: That's what I thought but not the case if it's defined in the way I did.

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally use RxJS to handle the logic and remove or add the control.

`isAdult$ | async` takes care of subscribing and unsubscribes on component destroy. Conceptually I think the age value should be true or false rather than strings '1' or '0'. This has added the benefit of `Validators.requiredTrue` doing what's needed on the age control.

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { map, Observable, tap } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="fg">
      Are you adult?
      <input type="radio" formControlName="Adult" [value]="true"/><label>Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" formControlName="Adult" [value]="false"/><label>No</label>

      <div *ngIf="isAdult$ | async">
        Enter your age: <input type="number" placeholder="18-120" formControlName="Age"/>
      </div>
    </form>

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Form - {{ fg.valid ? 'Valid': 'Invalid' }}
    <pre>{{ fg.value | json }}</pre>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {

  fg: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    Adult: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.requiredTrue]],
  });

  isAdult$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isAdult$ = this.fg.controls['Adult'].valueChanges.pipe(
      // add age control if user check `Yes` to `Are you an adult?`
      tap((value) => this.onAdultValueChangeAddOrRemoveAgeControl(value))
    );
  }

  onAdultValueChangeAddOrRemoveAgeControl(value) {
    if (value) {
      // check age of adult
      this.fg.addControl('Age',
        new FormControl(null, [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.min(18),
          Validators.max(120),
        ])
      );
    } else {
      // a child!
      this.fg.removeControl('Age');
    }
  }
}
```